# Why aren't existential types implemented in any mainstream language?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory

I'm talking about first-order existential types, as summarized [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), with `pack` as the introduction form that bundles up a type with an expression of that type, and `open` as the elimination form that unpacks the type and its representative expression.

This seems just as fundamental as parametric polymorphism (universal types), so I'm surprised that this construct isn't implemented in e.g. Haskell or OCaml. Does anyone know the reasons for this?

Comment: More details are needed. When one says existential type do they not mean a `witness` and a `proof` that the witness satisfies some property? If so, what is a "proof" in imperative/OO languages?

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy: No, they do not mean that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type

Comment: Learning things is a delight! Now I've more enjoyable articles to read;  Thanks Andrej!

Comment: Here is a bit of explanation to the less sophisticated readers who may want to understand the comments here. Constructively, we convince others that $\exists x.\varphi(x)$ holds if we can show an example (i.e., witness) $a$ and present an argument that $\varphi(a)$ holds. In some settings, we can consider types as logical statements, and terms as proofs to those statements. That is the background of Al-hassy's question. One possible choice of further reading may be Paul Taylor's _Practical Foundations of Mathematics_, Section 2.4.

Comment: Nevertheless, for the moment very few real-life programming languages possess such immediate correspondence to logic. Typed functional languages are usually good approximations, while imperative/OO languages are probably too far apart. For that reason witness-proof is technically not a way to think of `existential types' in imperative languages. However, forming and using existential types there involve a type $a$ and a value of type $\varphi(a)$ in a similar way. So to a programmer trying to express abstraction in their data and code, the mechanism is similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OCaml`'s idea of modules roughly correspond with existential types ;)

Let's set up some rough semantics in order to frame this correspondence properly. First, I'll give the intro/elimination rules for existential types (I'll only use a variable $\to$ type context $\Gamma$ for the sake of simplicity here):
$$
\frac{\Gamma \vdash e\{\alpha\mapsto \tau\} : \sigma\{\alpha\mapsto \tau\}}{\Gamma \vdash [\tau, e] : \exists \alpha. \sigma} ({\rm Pack}) ~~~~~~~ 
\frac{\Gamma \vdash e : \exists \alpha.\sigma ~~~ \Gamma, x:\sigma \vdash e' : \tau'}{\Gamma \vdash {\rm let} ~ [\alpha, x] = e ~ {\rm in} ~ e' : \tau'}({\rm Unpack})
$$
where $e\{\alpha \mapsto \tau\}$ substitutes all occurrences of the type variable $\alpha$ with the concrete type $\tau$. In practice, we will also decorate the packed form with its existential type in order to disambiguate the semantics.

Operationally, we have the context reductions:
$$
\frac{e \Downarrow v}{[\tau, e] \Downarrow [\tau, v]} ~~~~~~ \frac{e \Downarrow v}{{\rm let} ~ [\alpha, x] = e ~ {\rm in} ~ e' \Downarrow {\rm let} ~ [\alpha, x] = v ~ {\rm in} ~ e'}
$$
which corresponds to the reduction strategies that reduces the expressions in the existential packages and the expressions to be unpacked.

Finally, we have the extensional $\eta$-reduction rule:
$$
\frac{}{{\rm let} ~ [\alpha, x] = [\tau, v]_{\exists \alpha. \sigma} ~ {\rm in} ~ e \to e \{\alpha \mapsto \tau, x \mapsto v\}}
$$

So for example, the program
\begin{align*}
{\rm let} ~ [\alpha, x] &= [{\rm int}, (0, {\rm succ})]_{\exists \alpha. \alpha \times (\alpha \to \alpha)} ~ {\rm in} ~ ({\rm snd} ~ x : \alpha \to \alpha)({\rm fst} ~ x : \alpha)\\
&\to^{\eta} ({\rm snd} ~ (0, {\rm succ}) : {\rm int} \to {\rm int})({\rm fst} ~ (0, {\rm succ}) : {\rm int}) \\
&\to^* {\rm succ} ~ 0 \\
&\to^\beta 1
\end{align*}

This exact idea is present in `OCaml`'s concept of modules, save that the packed type must be a record (but which can be made to be isomorphic to any other OCaml type). For example, the creation of an existential type is done through the `module type` keyword:

```ocaml
module type Bundle =
sig
  type α
  val data : α * (α -> α)
end
```

This signature corresponds to the existential type $\exists \alpha. \alpha \times (\alpha \to \alpha)$. We can witness an inhabitant of this type by instantiating it with the `struct` keyword:

```ocaml
module BundleInt : Bundle = struct
  type α = int
  val data = (0, (+) 1)
end
```

which corresponds to the pack/intro $[{\rm int}, (0, (+) 1)]_{\exists \alpha. \alpha \times (\alpha \to \alpha)}$. Unfortunately, there is no explicit ${\rm let} \dots$ elimination form, but something like `open BundleInt` is equivalent to `let [α, data] = BundleInt in ...` where α and `data` are specified in the creation of the module type `Bundle`.

So while module types aren't exactly the same as your traditional existential types (the variables to be bound are explicitly pushed into the intro-form rather than in the elimination-form), their expressiveness are the same.

Comment: For some reason I don't remember seeing this answer, but thanks nonetheless! There actually is an `let open` construct in OCaml which seems to have nearly the same semantics as `unpack`. That said, there is one point I disagree with; you say that they're equally expressive, but with existential types, you can write a function parameterized by an existential type, whereas in OCaml you can't (you have to write *functors* parameterized by modules).